# gotoAndPlay in embedded movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I am working on an Air 2.6 project with an embedded SWF.

I am using the following embed code:

```
[Embed(source = "../../assets/click_feedback.swf", symbol="sub_circle")]
    [Bindable]
    public static var click_feedback:Class;
```

And the following code to get an instance of the click_feedback class:

```
private var cfb:MovieClip = new Assets.click_feedback() as MovieClip
```

The problems are:

The asset sub_circle has a frame labeled 'respond'. However, it just plays non stop whether or not the label is called with gotoAndPlay.

And, at the end of the animation, there is an Event.COMPLETE called, which is not being picked-up by my code.

I have tested the sub_circle asset in CS5 where I built it, and, in that environment it does not animate until 'respond' is called, and the event it triggers can be heard by my script.

Is this the correct way to handle embedded assets from an SWF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedding of separate symbols from swf in general isn't a good idea:

1. It slows the compilation of your project, because of compiler must transcode swf format.
2. Embedding delete ALL AS code from timeline (I didn't check, but may be it remove labels as well, and it can be the reason of your issue).

I recommend embed the hole swf file and loads its bytes in runtime, a little more code to handle the async loading, but much more freedom and flexibility in use:

1. you safe all as3 code
2. you can choose ApplicationDomain where to load classes
3. you can easily switching from Embedding to runtime swf loading by url at any time, if you want to separate the as code and art/sounds assets.
4. organize your assets to library with the AssetsManager (with api like `load(ByteArray or URL)`, `getSkin(name):DisplyObject`)

Code example adapted for your assets:

```
package
{
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;
import flash.system.LoaderContext;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

[SWF(width="800", height="200", backgroundColor="0x8B8B8B")]
public class astest extends Sprite
{
    [Embed(source="../../assets/click_feedback.swf", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
    private static const common_art:Class;

    private var loader:Loader;
    private var domain:ApplicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;

    public function astest()
    {
        init();
    }

    public function init():void
    {
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

        var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, domain);
        loaderContext.allowCodeImport = true;
        loader.loadBytes(new common_art() as ByteArray, loaderContext);
    }

    private function onLoaded(event:Event):void
    {
        var clip:MovieClip = getSkin("sub_circle") as MovieClip;
        addChild(clip);
    }

    private function getSkin(name:String):DisplayObject
    {
        if(domain.hasDefinition(name))
        {
            var clazz:Class = domain.getDefinition(name) as Class;
            return new clazz() as DisplayObject;

        }

        return null;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. HOwever, I am getting this error'[Fault] exception, information=SecurityError: Error #3226: Cannot import a SWF file when LoaderContext.allowCodeImport is false.' Any ideas?

Comment: just set the _LoaderContext.allowCodeImport_ flag to _true_ ) I updated the code (tested in as3 project, so missed this)

Comment: Thanks fsbmain. Works perfectly now.